# Quantifying symmetry across the diagonal in asymmetric dissimilarity matrix

Tags: matrix, distance

I've got a dissimilarity matrix constructed from pairwise similarity ratings. These similarity ratings are often asymmetrical (i.e., matrix[*i,j*] != matrix[*j,i*]), and the differences between the *ij* and *ji* values range from 0 to around 2.5.

My first-pass approach has been to calculate the difference between the absolute values *ij* and *ji*, creating a symmetrical matrix of the differences, then calculating descriptive statistics of this distance (i.e., asymmetry) for each column (corresponding to each stimulus). I'm thinking there has to be something more sophisticated that would provide a more accurate picture of this asymmetry.

I'm looking to quantify this asymmetry for the matrix as a whole, for each stimulus, and potentially in other ways as well. Perhaps there's a paper out there already discussing techniques for this, or maybe you have other suggestions?

Comment: Use as a distance the Frobenius norm of a matrix $B$ that when added to $A$ it would $A$ symmetric, $B$ should be $A - 0.5(A^T +A)$.

Comment: usεr11852, thank you for the reply. Here's some R code which I believe implements your suggestion. `mat <- matrix(runif(25, 1, 10), 5, 5)
diag(mat) <- 1

b <- mat[upper.tri(mat)]
a <- mat[lower.tri(mat)]

b.fnormed <- a - .5 * (t(a) + a)`    This returns all 0s. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your suggestion...would you mind expanding?

Comment: I am very interested in finding an answer to this question.